# Как связаны между собой сборки и пространства имен?

Tags: c#

Как связаны между собой сборки и пространства имен?

Comment: Можно сказать что ни как. 1. Любая сборка может содержать любое количество пространств имен. 2. Любое пространство имен может быть "размазано" по любому числу сборок. Никаких жестких ограничений нет. Или вы имели ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: Скорее всего, тут спрашивается про некие параметры, которые можно указать пространству имен, которые запретят или разрешат использовать соответствующее пространство имен вне сборки, которой он принадлежит.

Comment: так пространство имен - по сути агрегатная приставка к именам классов, не более. А вот у классов уже можно указать параметры использования

Comment: тогда я не знаю, такой вопрос в лабораторной

Comment: ок, попробую расписать подробнее, если ни кто не опередит

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Сборка**
Цитата с MSDN ([полный текст](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k3677y81(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Сборки являются структурными элементами приложений .NET Framework; они
>   составляют основную единицу развертывания, управления версиями,
>   повторного использования, областей действия активации и разрешений
>   безопасности. Сборка представляет собой коллекцию типов и ресурсов,
>   собранных для совместной работы и образующих логическую функциональную
>   единицу. Сборка предоставляет общеязыковой исполняющей среде сведения,
>   необходимые для распознавания реализаций типов. Для среды выполнения
>   тип не существует вне контекста сборки.

Никакого упоминания пространств имен, только типы (классы, структуры и т.д.).

**Пространство имен**
Цитата с MSDN ([полный текст](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0d941h9d.aspx)):

> В программировании на C# пространства имен используются с полной
>   нагрузкой по двум направлениям. Во-первых, платформа .NET Framework
>   использует пространства имен для организации множества классов.
>   Во-вторых, объявление собственного пространства имен поможет в
>   управлении областью действия имен классов и методов в крупных
>   программных проектах.

Опять же никакого упоминания сборок.

> тогда я не знаю, такой вопрос в лабораторной

Скорее всего от вас хотят услышать, что перед использованием `using SomeNameSpace;`, вы должны указать в проекте ссылку на сборку, в которой объявлены типы данного пространства имен. Но это не ни как не влияет на то, что сборки и пространства имен не имеют жесткой связи на уровне языка и платформы. Пространства имен - всего лишь агрегатная приставка к имени типа для явного указания принадлежности типа к определенной группе логически связанных типов, не более того. А вот типы, в отличие от пространств имен, имеют жесткую связь со сборкой в которой находятся, об этом можно подробнее почитать в первой ссылке.

Comment: А если я подключаю к проекту несколько сборок, где встречаются одинаковые пространства имен, то как мне разрешить конфликт?

Comment: а ни как, главное чтобы имена классов внутри пространства имен не пересекались. Вы даже можете дописать собственные классы в любое стандартное пространство имен, система позволяет, другой вопрос, что удобнее когда ваши типы в своем пространстве имен, а стандартные в своем.

Comment: @SanychGoilo возможно преподаватель и/или составитель вашей методички по лабам перепутал с Java, где разделение на "пакеты" по сути является разделением на папки. В .NET такого нет. Класс можно размазать на несколько файлов, и наоборот, запихнуть кучу классов в один файл. Про сборки уже написал. Полная свобода действий. Правда и ответственность за организацию кода тоже полностью лежит на вас.

Comment: @SanychGoilo Если у классов одинаковые *короткие* имена, но разные *полные* (с пространством имён), то в коде конфликт разрешается или включением только одного из пространств имён, или, если нужны оба, указанием более точного имени, или при помощи алиасов. Если у классов одинаковые полные имена, то уже сложнее: придётся добавлять внешние алиасы для сборок и в коде их вручную разруливать. Но это экзотическая ситуация.

Comment: @Discord а такую ситуацию тоже можно разрулить? вероятность возникновения конечно очень мала, но было бы интересно узнать как.

Comment: @rdorn [google://c# extern alias](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+extern+alias).