# Что содержит mscorlib.dll (.net) и вопрос по пересечению

Tags: c#, .net

Что содержит библиотека `mscorlib.dll`? Среда автоматически подключается данную библиотеку.

<strike>С чем связано пересечение типов в `mscorlib` и `System`?</strike>

**UPD:** Вопрос был неправильно сформулирован. Спасибо @VladD за ссылку: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd)

**UPD:** Возможно кому-нибудь пригодиться (пространства имен в сборках): [ссылка](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/namespacereference.aspx)

Comment: А можно пояснить, что означает «пересечение типов»?

Comment: @VladD прошу прощения, писал на ночь глядя. Пересечение пространства имен. Цитирую Албахари "C# 5.0 Справочник": "Пространства имен в .NET Framework пересекаются. Наиболее экстремальными примерами являются `mscorlib.dll` и `System.Core.dll` ..."

Comment: По поводу второй части вопроса, загляните [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/537405/10105).

Answer (score -1):

It's easier for you to see it yourself. Powershell .ps1 file.
Языковая локализация.
Из комментария @PashaPash "там кроме локализации много чего из System лежит."
Скорее всего так и есть, так как многие строки при работе этого кода пропускаются как пустые. Я полагаю, что возможно это бинарники локализации. Точного ответа у меня в данный момент нет.

```
$assemblies = ('mscorlib.dll')
$code = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
    internal static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint wID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

    public static string GetLocalizedPinToStartVerb(uint actionIndex)
    {
        int MAX_PATH = 255;
        StringBuilder szPinToStartLocalized = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
        IntPtr hShell32 = LoadLibrary("Shell32.dll");
        LoadString(hShell32, (uint)actionIndex, szPinToStartLocalized, MAX_PATH);
        return szPinToStartLocalized.ToString();
    }
'@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code `
         -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies `
         -Namespace Px `
         -UsingNamespace 'System.Text' `
         -Name Helper `
         -ErrorAction stop
cls
$count=''
for ($i=0;$i -lt 1000000;$i++){
    $localized=[Px.Helper]::GetLocalizedPinToStartVerb($i)
    if($localized -ne ''){
        "$i    $localized"
        if($count -eq ''){$count=$localized;}
        elseif($count -eq $localized){"$count - :) it must be end";break}

    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я поставил минус потом что: 1 - в русскоязычном сегменте stackoveflow.com пояснения нужно давать на русском языке. 2 - пояснение ничего не объясняет, и 3 - не понятно, что вообще вы этим кодом хотели сказать.

Comment: ну если искать по System.Text - то да, будет видна только "языковая локализация". Но вообще это просто Microsoft's Common Object Runtime Library, там кроме локализации много чего из System лежит.

Comment: @PashaPash Там есть какие-нибудь другие точки входа для текста? Потому, что результаты, которые я получил из этой dll, не очень то коррелируют с русскими названиями выдаваемыми COM, что не радует и не даёт надежд на автовзаимодействие с COM.

Comment: @PashaPash Верно, я получал строки как текст и было много пропущено (типа пусто). Это видно по счётчику. Именно про эти пропущенные строки вы говорите, я полагаю?